# How to add if condition in "initialRouteName" drawer React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i'm new in react native. i want to add if condition in initialRouteName like code below. when "notification" variable is null move to "MemberProfile" page. but if "notification" variable is not null move to "ReviewMember" page. i try it code but still move to "MemberProfile" page.  any solution?. 
this is my code

```
    var notification = null;
class DrawerMember extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      notifData: null
    };

    this.callCheck();
  }

  async callCheck() {
    await AsyncStorage.getItem("@tryCode:notification", (err, result) => {
      if (result != null) {
        this.setState({
          notifData: "testing data"
        });
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    notification = this.state.notifData;
    return <Root />;
  }
}
const Root = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    MemberProfile: {
      screen: MemberProfileScreen
    },
    ReviewMember: {
      screen: ReviewScreen
    }
  },
  {
    drawerPosition: "right",
    initialRouteName: notification == null ? "MemberProfile" : "ReviewMember",
    contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />,
  }
);

export default DrawerMember;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `Root` is created before the async function returns so `notification` is always null.

A possible way to solve this problem would be to use a `SwitchNavigator` as the first screen in your drawer. This navigator would be responsible for loading the notification and redirecting to the right screen.

Something along the lines of:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, AsyncStorage, ActivityIndicator, StatusBar } from 'react-native';


export default class DummySwitch extends React.Component {
  async componentDidMount() {
    this.listener = this.props.navigation.addListener('willFocus', async () => {
      const notification = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@tryCode:notification');
      if (notification === null) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('MemberProfile');
      }
      else {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('ReviewMember');
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <ActivityIndicator />
        <StatusBar barStyle='default' />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, the switch screen just displays a loading button while accessing the async storage and deciding which route to take.

Then you define the drawer as usual but you add the switch screen as the initial route. You can also hide the label if you want by defining your own `drawerLabel`:

```js
export default createDrawerNavigator({
  Switch: {
    screen: Switch,
    navigationOptions: () => ({
      drawerLabel: () => null,
    }),
  },
  MemberProfile: {
    screen: MemberProfileScreen,
  },
  ReviewMember: {
    screen: ReviewScreen,
  },
}, { initialRouteName: 'Switch' });
```

This is it, the drawer now selects the route based on your async storage.